# Spring Boot application not able to connect to MySQL database running in Docker container

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, docker-compose

`application.yml`:

```
spring:
  profiles: container
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_NAME}
    username: ${DATABASE_USER}
    password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    initialize: true
    tomcat:
      max-active: 1
jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

---

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.1'
services: 
  demo-mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
  spring-boot-app:
    image: chinmayee/chinmayee
    depends_on:
      - demo-mysql
    ports:
      - 9090:8080
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=demo-mysql
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306
      - DATABASE_NAME=chinmayee
      - DATABASE_USER=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
```

---

`pom.xml` snippets:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.46</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My application is not able to connect to the Db running in container. I see this error:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:301) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
```

Comment: where is mysql database running? in host machine or docker container?

Comment: Yuor `DATABASE_HOST` wrong

Comment: mysql is running on docker container

Comment: What is the log on the demo-mysql service? Is it ok, it it listening ? If you do a `docker-compose down  spring-boot-app && docker-compose up  spring-boot-app` is it better?

Comment: Have you configured MySQL to allow remote connections ?

See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/793058/can-not-access-mysql-docker)

Answer (score 0):

I think port 3306 on container demo-mysql is not forwarded

try adding the ports config

```
version: '3.1'
services: 
  demo-mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```